# Set color for even rows using <s:set> - Struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to give dynamic color/style for even rows of the table. Below is my code but it is not giving me required output.

```
<table>
   <s:iterator value="allMonths" status="incr">
   <style>
    .evenRow{background-color: yellow;}
    .oddRow{background-color: orange;}
   </style>
   <tr>

   <s:if test="#incr.count%2 ==0">
    <s:set var="clr" value="evenRow"></s:set>
   </s:if>

   <s:else>
    <s:set var="clr" value="oddRow"></s:set>
   </s:else>

        <td class="%{#clr}">Month:</font> <s:property/></td>
        <%-- <td class="%{clr}">Month:</font> <s:property/></td> --%>
        <%-- <td class="clr">Month:</font> <s:property/></td> --%>
    </tr>
   </s:iterator>
</table>
```

**index.jsp**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<body>
<s:form action="clickAction">

    <s:textfield name="beanobject.uname" label="Enter Username" /><br>
    <s:textfield name="beanobject.age" label="Enter Age" /><br>
    <s:textfield name="beanobject.sex" label="sex" /><br>
    <s:submit value="Submit" align="center" /> 
    <s:submit value="Clear" align="center" action="clearAction"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyAction.java**

```
    ---imports---

public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{
    private MyBean beanobject;
    private List<String> allMonths;

    //Getters & Setters

    public String execute(){    
        System.out.println("execute");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String click()
    {   
        allMonths = new ArrayList<String>();
        allMonths.add("Jan");
        allMonths.add("Feb");
        allMonths.add("Mar");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String clear(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I also tried using **"bgcolor"** attribute but with no success. What am I missing?

*Provided required code. I am just hardcoding values in list in ActionClass*

Comment: Please include a sample of the rendered HTML.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have edited the question. Can you check?

Comment: Please include a sample of the rendered HTML. We don't know what's actually happening because we can't see your screen. (We *do* know, but just looking at the rendered HTML would have immediately clarified the situation--that's why I asked for it. And you should have looked at it.)

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming JSP understands OGNL; it does not. JSP understands JSP EL.

OGNL is strictly within S2 custom tags, not generic JSP.